# Can't get GLFW to work even if glfwInit() returns 1

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glfw

I've already set `GLFW` library up and according to it's User Guide, I should use `glfwInit()` function to initialize it. After that I should be able to - for example - call callback function after I press key on my keyboard, but this function wasn't called, so I tried with something easier - getting mouse position. But it also doesn't work, so I assume that something is wrong with my whole GLFW.

This is main loop for my application:

```
while (!m_exit)
{

    int x, y;
    glfwGetMousePos(&x, &y);
    glfwPollEvents();
    gameCycle();                        // Do one cycle

    while (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
    {
        // Check the pressence of commands
        if (!GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            return msg.wParam; // Hand the control on to system
        }

        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    }
}
```

Also before this loop, I initialize my `GLFW`:

```
// Initialize GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

glfwSetKeyCallback(processKeys);

// Main message loop:
int loopRet = g_pGameAppLayer->mainLoop();
```

When I check values which are saved in `x` and `y` variables, I get only -858993460 which indicates that no value is passed to them.

So what am I missing in setting `GLFW` up?

Comment: If you are using GLFW, why are you explicitly pumping Win32 messages?

Comment: @rioki Because I didn't know I shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is here:

> After that I should be able to - for example - call callback function after I press key on my keyboard

No, you shouldn't. Until you have created a *window* with GLFW, you can't get input. This is generally true of many windowing systems; you only get input if you have a window.

Comment: Thank you Nicol, I thought that I may be able to use GLFW only for handle input, because I already had window created without using GLFW.